# Setting parent node in Tree

Tags: java, tree

I'm currently trying to create and solve a slider puzzle using BFS. I created my own object called gamestate to store the parent gamestate and the new gamestate. The problem I'm having is I'm not correctly storing the parent state, as when I call to get all adjacent vertices for my tree they aren't using their own parent. Let me show my tests to explain more. Here is my GameState object code -

```
public class GameState {
public int[][] state; //state of the puzzle
public GameState parent; //parent in the game tree

public GameState() {
    //initialize state to zeros, parent to null
    state = new int[0][0];
    parent = null;
}

public GameState(int[][] state) {
    //initialize this.state to state, parent to null
    this.state = new int[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            this.state[i][j] = state[i][j];
        }
    }

    parent = null;
}

public GameState(int[][] state, GameState parent) {
    //initialize this.state to state, this.parent to parent
    this.state = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            this.state[i][j] = state[i][j];
        }
    }

    this.parent = parent;
}

public GameState swapRight(GameState s, int row, int col) {
    //helper function to swap blank space with right block
    // row and col are where the zero index is
    s.parent = s;
    int temp = state[row][col+1];
    s.state[row][col+1] = state[row][col];
    s.state[row][col] = temp;

    return s;

}

public GameState swapLeft(GameState s, int row, int col) {
    //helper function to swap blank space with left block
    s.parent = s;
    int temp = state[row][col]; // Mark zero as temp
    s.state[row][col] = state[row][col-1];
    s.state[row][col-1] = temp;

    return s;
}

public GameState swapUp(GameState s, int row, int col) {
    s.parent = s;
    int temp = state[row][col]; // Mark zero as temp
    s.state[row][col] = state[row-1][col];
    s.state[row-1][col] = temp;

    return s;
}

public GameState swapDown(GameState s, int row, int col) {
    //helper function to swap blank space with down block
    s.parent = s;
    int temp = state[row][col];
    s.state[row][col] = state[row+1][col];
    s.state[row+1][col] = temp;

    return s;
}

public boolean isEnd() {
    //helper function to check if the GameState is the end state e.g.
    //0 1 2
    //3 4 5
    //6 7 8

    //Stores indexes of zero element

    GameState testEnd = new GameState();

    int[][] t1 = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
    int[][] t2 = {{8,0,1},{2,3,4},{5,6,7}};
    int[][] t3 = {{7,8,0},{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int[][] t4 = {{6,7,8},{0,1,2},{3,4,5}};
    int[][] t5 = {{5,6,7},{8,0,1},{2,3,4}};
    int[][] t6 = {{4,5,6},{7,8,0},{1,2,3}};
    int[][] t7 = {{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,1,2}};
    int[][] t8 = {{2,3,4},{5,6,7},{8,0,1}};
    int[][] t9 = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,0}};

    testEnd.state = t1;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t2;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t3;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t4;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t5;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t6;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t7;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t8;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;
    testEnd.state = t9;
    if(this.equals(testEnd)) return true;

    return false;

}

public ArrayList<GameState> getAdjacent() {
    //Use the swap functions to generate the new vertices of the tree
    //Beware of the boundary conditions, i.e. don’t swap left when you are
    //already on the left edge

    ArrayList<GameState> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    //Gets index of our zero element
    for (int i = 0 ; i < this.state.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.state.length; j++) {
            if (this.state[i][j] == 0) {
                row = i;
                col = j;
            }
        }
    }


    //Checking if we can swap up
    if(row != 0) {
        vertices.add(swapUp(this, row, col));
    }


    //Checking if we can swap down
    if(row != 2) {
        vertices.add(swapDown(this, row, col));
    }

    //Checking if we can swap left
    if(col != 0) {
        vertices.add(swapLeft(this, row, col));
    }

    //Checking if we can swap right
    if(col != 2) {
        vertices.add(swapRight(this, row, col));
    }

    return vertices;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    //test that 2 GameStates are equal

    if (!(o instanceof GameState)) return false;
    GameState that = (GameState) o;
    return Arrays.deepEquals(this.state, that.state);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // print out the int[][] array in a 3x3 block e.g.
    //0 1 2
    //3 4 5
    //6 7 8

    String result = Arrays
            .stream(state)
            .map(Arrays::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    return result;
}
```

}

The issue I'm occurring is within my main method I'm testing if calling getAdjacent results in 1-4 different scenarios, but they are all printing the same scenario. My main method calls -

```
    int[][] tArr = {{1,5,2},{3,4,0},{6,8,7}}; //start state, i.e. tree root
    GameState start = new GameState(tArr,null); // state with tArr state, null parent
    explored = new ArrayList<GameState>();
    frontier = new ArrayDeque<GameState>();


    frontier.add(start);


    while(!frontier.isEmpty())
    {
        explored.add(frontier.remove());
        System.out.println(start);

        if(start.isEnd())
        {
            break;
        }


        ArrayList<GameState> vertices = start.getAdjacent();
        System.out.println(vertices.size());
        for(int i=0; i<vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            if(!explored.contains(vertices.get(i)))
            {
                frontier.add(vertices.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println(vertices.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println(frontier.size());


    }
```

And this is the output I'm receiving -

```
[1, 5, 2]
[3, 4, 0]
[6, 8, 7]
3
0
[1, 5, 0]
[3, 7, 4]
[6, 8, 2]
1
[1, 5, 0]
[3, 7, 4]
[6, 8, 2]
2
[1, 5, 0]
[3, 7, 4]
[6, 8, 2]
0
```

As you can see, it is only swapping up.

Comment: Still have been unable to solve this - any help?